# How to save user inputs from dialog to a RecyclerView as an item?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I Have implemented an Add/Edit dialog for recyclerview(first recyclerview) item, which will ask the user for inputs.

Basically what I need to know is to take user inputs from the dialog and save them as items to another RecyclerView(RecyclerView two), which is within a fragment?

A code or a sample will even be more than welcome. Following is the code so far in the adapter class for my attempt.

```
public class ContReceiptsAdapter extends   RecyclerView.Adapter<ContReceiptsAdapter.ReceiptsViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Contract> contracts;
Context mContext;
String inPending;
//for the details dialog
EditText et_number, contract_id_val, product_type_val, mobile_number_ADialog;
//    ImageView btn_add_item;
//--to set to add item dialog
public TextView contract_number, vehicle_number, contract_number_ADialog, vehicle_number_ADialog ;
CheckBox checkbox_pending;

private ItemOnClickListener mListener;

public interface ItemOnClickListener {
void onItemClicked(View view,int index);

void onItemDelete(int index);

void onItemAdd(int index);
}

public void setmListener(ItemOnClickListener listener) {
this.mListener = listener;
}

public ContReceiptsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contract> contractList) {
contracts = contractList;
mContext = context;
}

public class ReceiptsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView tv_contract, tvVehicleN, tvContractType;
ImageView btn_add_item;
LinearLayout detailsLayout;

public ReceiptsViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    detailsLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_details_item_id);
    tv_contract = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_contract);
    tvVehicleN = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvVehicleN);
    tvContractType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvContractType);
    btn_add_item = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_item);
}
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ContReceiptsAdapter.ReceiptsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.receipt_tobe_added_rv_item, viewGroup, false);

final ReceiptsViewHolder receiptsViewHolder = new ReceiptsViewHolder(view);

//dialog ini
//        ShowDetails();
final Dialog detailedDialog = new Dialog(this.mContext);
detailedDialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_details);

receiptsViewHolder.detailsLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //click view dto show the detaileds view of the list item
        contract_number = detailedDialog.findViewById(R.id.contract_id_val);
        vehicle_number = detailedDialog.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_num_val);
            contract_number.setText(contracts.get(receiptsViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getContractNumber());
            vehicle_number.setText(contracts.get(receiptsViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getVehicleNumber());
        detailedDialog.show();
        detailedDialog.setCancelable(true);
    }
});

return receiptsViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ContReceiptsAdapter.ReceiptsViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

viewHolder.itemView.setTag(contracts.get(i));

viewHolder.tv_contract.setText(contracts.get(i).getContractNumber());
viewHolder.tvVehicleN.setText(contracts.get(i).getVehicleNumber());
viewHolder.tvContractType.setText(contracts.get(i).getContractType());

final Dialog AddItemDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
AddItemDialog.setContentView(R.layout.fragment_add_receipt);

viewHolder.btn_add_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
 //                ShowDetails();
        contract_number_ADialog = AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.contract_id_val_add);
            contract_number_ADialog.setText(contracts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getContractNumber());
        vehicle_number_ADialog = AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.product_type_val_add);
        vehicle_number_ADialog.setText(contracts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getVehicleNumber());
//this mobile number is an iput taken from user
        mobile_number_ADialog = AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.et_number_add);
        mobile_number_ADialog.setText(contracts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getMobileNumber());
//this checkbox value is also taken from user 
        checkbox_pending = AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_pending_add);
            checkbox_pending.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(contracts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPendingState()));
        Button btn_cancel_receipt = AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_receipt);
        Button btn_add_receipt =AddItemDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_receipt);

        AddItemDialog.show();
        AddItemDialog.setCancelable(true);

        btn_cancel_receipt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //this will close/cancel the user input dialog
                AddItemDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        btn_add_receipt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             //this is where i will get the inputs from edit/input dialog
             //and try to pass those values to the second recycleview which will be added as an item
                //add item to rv2
            }
        });

    }
});
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return contracts.size();
}

private void addAnItem() {
   contract_number_ADialog.setText(contracts.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getContractNumber());
}
```

Comment: take input from your dialog , add items into list and notify data from this list into RecyclerView

Comment: thanks Draft. i worked out that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      btn_add_receipt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Create a Contract object, since list is of Contract type
            // then add the user input to contract model, either through constructor or setter
            // adn finally pass to this method
            addItem(Contract contract);

        }
    });

}

private void addItem(Contract contract) {
    contracts.add(Contract contract);
    notifyDataSetChanged;
}
```

All codes are inside adapter

Comment: I have a contract object made for the first recyclerview. is it possible to use that same object for the second recyclerview?

Comment: Yeah, just change the value through your setters

Comment: great, glad it helped.

Comment: now im trying to figure out how to manage two different recyclerviews using the same adapter or viewholder... any ideas?